# Retrieving a Java object after displaying its attribute

Tags: java, oop, object

```
ArrayList<ShiftModel> ShiftList = db.getAllShifts();     

for(int i = 0; i < ShiftList.size(); i = i + 1   )
{   
    //Displays a nicely formatted String in a combobox 
    comboBox.addItem(ShiftList.get(i).getComboBoxDisplay()); 
}

//returns a String from the combobox I just populated
table.getValueAt(3, 1)
```

What I want to do is use

```
table.getValueAt(3, 1)
```

and it to return the ShiftModel object rather than the formatted String I used to display it.

Any ideas? Much appreciated.

Comment: Then store the object itself in the model, instead of a String. And override itstoString() method, or use a renderer to display it the way you like. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get` method of `ArrayList` itself, to get the required object, e.g.:

```
ShiftModel modelObject = ShiftList.get(3);
```

This will return the value present at `index` 3. Please note that you need to make sure that the list contains atleast `index + 1` elements before retriving the value present at `index` postition. Otherwise you will get `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

[Here's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)) the jacadoc of `get` method.